# Product db association for e-commerce

Tags: postgresql, database-design

#### Terms related to E-commerce

In ecommerce setup we have Products and Variants.
Variants are also products but they vary on some attributes.

eg: A T-shirt can vary on `Size` and `Color` attributes.
Let say we have following options for `Size` and `Color` attributes 
`Color` : Red, Green
`Size`: Small, Large

Then we can have 4 Variants for that T-Shirt

---

Following terms will be used throughout the question:

**Option Type** : Product attributes that help in creating variants **eg**: Size, Color, Material etc..

**Option Value** : Values that are possible for particular Option types. **eg**: `Size` option type can have following option values `Small`, `Medium`, `Large`, `Extra-Large`

**Variation theme** : Variation theme is list of `option type` that are needed to create a variant

**Prototype**: Prototype is nothing but template for a product. Prototype help us creating a product with ease.
It stores following information:
- Product properties
- Varition themes

### Goal

---

We have 2 Roles: `Admin`, `Seller`

Following are the things that above Roles can do

#### Admin can

- Create product category(taxon) and associate it with the product `prototype`
- Associate prototype with variation themes for a particular product category
- Create variation theme

  - Create and Associate option types for variation theme
  - Create default template option values for particular option type

    - **eg:** `Size` option type can have `S`, `M`, `L`, `XL` option values
  - Can add more default template values if needed for a option type

#### Seller can

- Create a product
- Choose variation theme for product

  - Populate option type for selected variation theme.
  - Can either select default template option values for option type **OR** add a new option value for the option type

Following are some contraints that need to be kept in mind

- Seller sees the possible option values for an option type set by the Admin
- When seller adds new option value for option type, it should not affect the option values added by Admin

## DB design

#### Diagram  [Diagram image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4W4Q9.png)

[image]

Lets see if above db design adhere to the goals

- **Admin can create product category(taxon) and associate it with  prototype.**

  - `Taxon` is a category node and stores prototype key and each category can have one prototype. This ensures that we always have one category associated to one one prototype.
- **Associate prototype with variation themes for a particular product category.**

  - `Variation theme` store prototype id and protoype can have many variation themes.
- **Admin can create and associate option types for variation theme**

  - `Variation theme` has many `Option types` through `theme_option_types` table.
- **Admin can create default template option values for particular option type.**

  - `Option values` for particular `option type` can be stored in `template_option_value`. Eg. the admin can set `s`,`m`,`l`,`xl` as default values which the sellers can select while creating products.
  - One `option type` can have many `option values`.
- **Seller can create product and select variation theme for a product.**

  - To create a product seller has to select the category(taxon) under which the product may fall. eg: Smartphone product can fall under `Electronics => Mobiles & Accessories => Smartphones & Basic Mobiles => Smartphones`.
  - As product associate directly with a category(`taxon`) then the product prototype is easy to find.
- **Populate option type for selected variation theme.**

  - `Prototype` has many `variation themes`, so `variants` for `product` can be created based on `option type` in the selected theme.

  [image]
- **Seller can either select default template option values for option type**

  - User can be shown the possible option values from the `template_option_values` for the option type.

  [image]
- **Seller can add new option type for option type**

  - As the option values are stored in different table ie. `variant_option_values`, we can add as many option value for option type of that variant.
  - Also the new value does not get added in the default options added by admin because we are maintaining different table for option values of variants.

#### Painpoints

- The values is stored in different table (`variant_option_values`), so the values will get repeated when the seller selects option values mostly added by admin.
- I am also not sure that my design is the best way to do to achieve the goals. Need validations and critics.

Comment: Do you have a finished design for this database? I have the same problem as you, and I am looking for a solution. If yes, can you give me a reference on how to design it?